# How to extract individual macroblock types and their corresponding motion vectors

Tags: ffmpeg, video, compression

I need to make a pair for each macroblock from a frame of a video containing its type and motion vector.

I extracted motion vectors by using the python module of [mv-extractor](https://github.com/LukasBommes/mv-extractor).

For macroblock type I used ffmpeg command: `ffmpeg -threads 1 -debug 'mb_type' -i file.h264 -f null -`

The info received from ffmpeg command doesn't match with the location of motion vectors extracted (Macroblocks which are divided into smaller blocks of size 8X16 or 16X8 do not match with the info of macroblock size received in motion vector info). Also, the ffmpeg command for extracting macroblock type doesn't work properly on some videos.

Can you please tell a more streamlined way of doing this task.